# WordPress WP Query on a Page Template: Adding Scheduled Posts to the array

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

Got a WordPress page template that calls up 15 posts. No problem there. However, the client is kind of using the blog as an event calendar of sorts, so he's got a bunch of scheduled posts that display future dates he wants to appear in the feed. I thought this would simply do it:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=15' . 'post_status=future' . '&paged='.$paged);
```

But not the case. What would make scheduled posts appear in the Query?

Comment: I solved this in the past using a custom field in which the date of celebration would be introduced, then query events in that page (or widget) using that date, and not the creation date of the post.

Comment: Hear you. Unfortunately, that's not a solution here as I'm taking over this site and so I've got to play with what they already have.